# Importing csv files using PHP , It says itis imported yet its not

Tags: php, csv, import

I was testing it and yes it let me select a file and sai that i "have successfully imported" the file
and yet when i looked at my database it doesnt imported ...
.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

this is my function.php

```
             if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
                $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $db = "lcho_login";

            try {

                $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
                  if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
                     {
                        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
                        while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                         {


                           $sql = "INSERT into lcho_dengue_activities (district_id,barangay_id,month,year,dengue_ind1,dengue_ind2,dengue_ind3,dengue_ind4,dengue_ind5,dengue_ind6,dengue_ind7,dengue_ind8,dengue_ind9,dengue_ind10,dengue_ind11) 
                               values ('".$getData[0]."','".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."','".$getData[3]."','".$getData[4]."','".$getData[5]."','".$getData[6]."','".$getData[7]."','".$getData[8]."','".$getData[9]."','".$getData[10]."')";
                               echo "yes";
                               $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            if(!isset($result))
                            {
                                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                                        alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                                        window.location = \"imports.php\"
                                      </script>";       
                            }
                            else {
                                  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                                    alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                                    window.location = \"imports.php\"
                                </script>";
                            }
                         }

                         fclose($file); 
                     }
                }
            catch(exception $e)
                {
                echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
                return $conn;   

                    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];      



                }    


             ?>
```

and this is my imports.php

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">

            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            </head>

            <body>
                <div id="wrap">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">

                            <form class="form-horizontal" action="functions.php" method="post" name="upload_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <fieldset>

                                    <!-- Form Name -->
                                    <legend>Form Name</legend>

                                    <!-- File Button -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filebutton">Select File</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="input-large">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Button -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton">Import data</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="Import" class="btn btn-primary button-loading" data-loading-text="Loading...">Import</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </fieldset>
                            </form>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>

            </html>
```

Comment: You're checking for isset. The variable is set, it's just false. So you need to check for `if(!$result)`, and make sure you check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). That said, you really ought to be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to avoid quoting issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious from your shown code that you're not passing all the columns value on your `$sql` query while trying to insert on table. Because I can see you've **15** columns but only passing **11** values. Why?

```
$sql = "INSERT into lcho_dengue_activities (district_id,barangay_id,month,year,dengue_ind1,dengue_ind2,dengue_ind3,dengue_ind4,dengue_ind5,dengue_ind6,dengue_ind7,dengue_ind8,dengue_ind9,dengue_ind10,dengue_ind11) values('".$getData[0]."','".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."','".$getData[3]."','".$getData[4]."','".$getData[5]."','".$getData[6]."','".$getData[7]."','".$getData[8]."','".$getData[9]."','".$getData[10]."')";

  // Perform a query, check for error
  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
     echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

**Because of the column and passed value number mismatch** the `mysqli_query($con,$sql)` function returning `false` for `$result` so `if(!isset($result))` line evaluates `false` and goes to else block which contains the message `CSV File has been successfully Imported.`